# UML code engineering for PHP - is it possible?

Tags: java, php, uml

I am currently in the process of making a brainstorm idea and mockup phase in my latest project. I am done with the UI design and the general cloudy thingy idea how all should work.

Now i want to start the UML structure planing, and i am stuck on a problem, which is.

Find a tool which is as good for code abstraction as Sprax Enterprise Architect, but one which is made for PHP development and easy to use.

EA is great, but TOO much clunky and documentation based, and the damn  thing always thinks Java is the end of all things and creates a new object always in Java and not PHP format.

So my question is:

Is there a UML modeling tool which supports UML modeling and PHP code IMPORT/EXPORT??? And which is not so clunky as SPRAX?

Comment: "SPRAX is great, but TO much clunky and documentation based" - What do you mean? EA has awful documentation!

Comment: Yes, documentation is awful, but when you get to know it you start to like it, it can correctly represent most class corelations, reverse engenier a class structure connections and all kinds of crazy stuff. really usful on biger loong living applications

Comment: "documentation is awful, but when you get to know it you start to like it"... That sounds a bit masochistic, doesn't it? :-)... I know that many people use it. But if I have to choose among several bad tools, it doesn't make any of these good. One of them always will be not so bad as others, but that doesn't make it a GOOD tool... And notice, it is YOU who wants a tool OTHER than EA, not me.

Comment: As told, i need an simpler alternative, tht is why i want to move from EA. It is to time consuming, but i cant work without a tool which can make a graphical representation from interfaces and bases classes.

Answer (score 0):

- Sparx EA does have support for PHP code generation and back engineering. Only it is for free for one month only. Viz. http://www.sparxsystems.com/platforms/php_uml.html

> Find a tool which is as good for code abstraction as Sprax enterprice Architect

- Code generation and back engineering work as some helping functions. Do not think that you can really generate applications from diagrams or usable diagrams fro code. You are getting some ... <sup><sub>(substitute any forbidden on this server word here)</sub></sup> that saves some typing, but adds greatly to editing. There are no **good** tools for code generation from UML. It is impossible due to UML itself. The dairy dream of making app in UML is on the same reality level as your child dreams of a ride in a kangaroo pocket.
- If you want [back]engineering, you have to use a modelling tool. All modelling tools are heavy, bulky and inconvenient. Diagramming tools are much more convenient, but they cannot have any code generation. VP-UML [has](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpumluserguide/276/330/7341_instantgener.html) PHP engineering, too, and it has a bit easier GUI. But it is also a modelling tool and it is strict and bulky, too. And as a tool for free diagrams it is far less convenient, that EA. And sooner or later you always MUST use free diagramming elements.
- Do not think that Java is really supported by UML tools. Oh, it is, but only on the level of "school" projects. Any modern serious Java programming is heavily based on use of anonymous classes, but no tool exists that will allow you to show two anonymous classes in one parent class on a class diagram. And even one anonymous class showing is not easy and understandable. So, even modelling the Java programs is problematic. Let alone code engineering.
- The only really useful **automatic** engineering tools are these that  make class diagrams at every build from the JavaDoc. It is simply a graphical form of JavaDoc. It works. And it is useful because it is really automatic and you always have **actual** diagrams. I can't imagine such tool for PHP, because PHP has no builds.

Comment: I am not intending to use the tool for complete code generation. Just for base class structures and interface planing so i can use it to keep the documentation with umls acurate as i progress with coding. Like i change aabstract interface in PHP but i dont have to reimport thedamn thing to sprax and he dous not write the god damn thing in java...

Comment: And i have to object you can do really great stuff with class implementatoin diagrams and descriptions, even import code comments in the project and vice versa

Comment: @Sangoku 1. You have asked for PHP code generation. I have given you 2 references. Where is the problem? 2. Please, check your text. You are giving others really a hard work. It is not very polite. I can't understand your second comment at all, sorry. Only something about that code generator can be useful. Yes, it can, I agree. But not constantly. And because it doesn't keep the diagram up to code automatically, the diagrams are ALWAYS obsolete.

Comment: Hard time not intended, Thank you for the sugestion, am loking into it as i write(englisch is not my native lang.)  As for second coment, i am using this aproch when ic ode, make logical uml and make the uml elements composite and implement them on principe 1 eml element 1 Packege 1 namespace and so on. I use this usualy for documentation only, but it sux after a year of coding to import every class.

Comment: @Sangoku I am about 300km to N from you. English is not my language, too... Have you tried VP-UML?